# Vaadin 14.1.17 startup very slow

Tags: performance, spring-boot, vaadin, startup, vaadin14

i'm testing the empty Vaadin project generated from the "Get Started" page ([here](https://vaadin.com/start/latest))

I'm facing very slow startup time (up to 6 minutes) and i'm not really understanding what's going on, i tried setting vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true but it doesn't solve the issue.

Is there a way to produce a more verbose startup log? Below you can find the current log.

```
2020-02-13 09:18:14.399  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] it.my-project.Application     : Starting Application on XCR10248 with PID 12084 (C:\Dev\workspace-eclipse-2019\my-project\target\classes started by cr10248 in C:\Dev\workspace-eclipse-2019\my-project)
2020-02-13 09:18:14.399  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] it.my-project.Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-13 09:18:14.446  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-02-13 09:18:14.446  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-02-13 09:18:15.868  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-02-13 09:18:15.872  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-02-13 09:18:15.872  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2020-02-13 09:18:16.326  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-02-13 09:18:16.326  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1880 ms
2020-02-13 09:18:19.373  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for subclasses and classes with annotations took 2 seconds
2020-02-13 09:18:19.381  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.server.startup.DevModeInitializer  : Starting dev-mode updaters in C:\Dev\workspace-eclipse-2019\my-project folder.
2020-02-13 09:18:19.412  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] dev-updater                              : Visited 94 classes. Took 31 ms.
2020-02-13 09:18:19.444  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] dev-updater                              : Skipping `npm install`.
2020-02-13 09:18:19.444  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] dev-updater                              : Copying frontend resources from jar files ...
2020-02-13 09:18:19.819  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] dev-updater                              : Visited 12 resources. Took 372 ms.
2020-02-13 09:18:19.850  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] dev-updater                              : No js modules to update 'C:\Dev\workspace-eclipse-2019\my-project\target\frontend\generated-flow-imports.js' file
2020-02-13 09:24:48.821  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] dev-webpack                              : Starting webpack-dev-server, port: 63432 dir: C:\Dev\workspace-eclipse-2019\my-project
2020-02-13 09:24:48.951  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] dev-webpack                              : Running webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2020-02-13 09:25:18.986  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] dev-webpack                              : Webpack startup and compilation completed in 30165ms
2020-02-13 09:25:19.211  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-02-13 09:25:19.649  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-02-13 09:25:19.836  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-02-13 09:25:19.836  INFO 12084 --- [  restartedMain] it.my-project.Application     : Started Application in 425.889 seconds (JVM running for 427.06)
```

Thanks
Davide

Comment: NPM downloads getting dropped at your "corporate" firewall/missing proxy setup?

Comment: The first time that you install/run a vaadin 14 project it is normal to take this long, as npm needs to download a whole lot of node_modules. Can you try again and see if it's faster now?

Comment: Note, in Vaadin 14.2 npm will be replaced with pnpm, which has global dependency cache folder in your computer same way as maven does. I.e. then if you create a new project using same Vaadin version, modules are not being downloaded again, but copied from cache.

Comment: see my answer, it seem it was a Eclipse-related issue (imho Eclipse IS a issue xD)

Comment: @TatuLund this is huge news! sounds great, looking forward to that.

Answer (score 3):

I answer my own question since i found (at least i hope :D) the "solution".

Like almost ALWAYS, Eclipse didn't manage to understand what's going on with project generated static resources (JS files in this case) and for some reason a full build seems to be performed every time, resulting in long waitings.

Simply doing a F5 on project root did the trick and now the startup takes 5 seconds.

Hope this could help other developers.

Comment: Can you mention the name of the menu command being executed by F5? And your version of Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse version is 2019-09 R (4.13.0).
F5 is a simple refresh on project root, just right click on project name -> Refresh